# Writing a SpringData method using Like "%"

Tags: spring-data

I need to write the SpringData method using Like "%".

For example,

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/ users / {firstname} / {lastname}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

List <User> users = findByFirstnameLikeAndLastnameLike (firstname, lastname);
```

In this case, if both firstname and lastname are equal to %, then all User must return.

I now return a blank page, it works only if both firstname and lastname have some value

Answer (score 0):

I think that's the wrong SQL.

This is really FOUR queries, not one:

1. SELECT *
2. SELECT * WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '%X'
3. SELECT * WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE '%Y'
4. SELECT * WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '%X' AND LAST_NAME LIKE '%Y'

You should not try to cover all four cases in a single query.

I would write a DAO with four distinct methods and have the controller choose which one to call based on the input parameters.

Your contract with users should spell out the REST URL differences between the four cases.  It's confusing without a contract.  Are first and last name required?  I can't know unless you tell me.